# Full information not getting from database query to datatable asp.net c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

When I'm running a query in MySql Database i got the following result

```
08/03/2014,07/03/2014,06/03/2014,05/03/2014,04/03/2014,03/03/2014,02/03/2014,01/03/2014,28/02/2014,27/02/2014,26/02/2014,25/02/2014,24/02/2014,23/02/2014,22/02/2014,21/02/2014,20/02/2014,19/02/2014,18/02/2014,17/02/2014,16/02/2014,15/02/2014,14/02/2014,13/02/2014,12/02/2014,11/02/2014
```

but when i used the same query and try to fill `DataTable` in `asp.net c#`, only `256` characters got like below

```
08/03/2014,07/03/2014,06/03/2014,05/03/2014,04/03/2014,03/03/2014,02/03/2014,01/03/2014,28/02/2014,27/02/2014,26/02/2014,25/02/2014,24/02/2014,23/02/2014,22/02/2014,21/02/2014,20/02/2014,19/02/2014,18/02/2014,17/02/2014,16/02/2014,15/02/2014,14/02/2014,13/
```

Any help will be appreciated. Whats the problem caused? and how to overcome it?

this is my query, and i use this query to fill the `DataTable`

```
SELECT DISTINCT  GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(p.PubDate, '%d/%m/%Y') ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(PubDate, '%Y%m%d') DESC SEPARATOR ',' ) AS `Column` FROM 

 (SELECT `ID`, COUNT(DISTINCT `BookUnitID`) AS `I_UnitID` 
 FROM `publishdates` 
 WHERE `IsActive`='T' 
 GROUP BY `ID`) b

 LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT `ID`,`PubDate`, COUNT(DISTINCT `BookUnitID`) AS `I_UnitID` 
 FROM `publishdates` 
 WHERE `IsActive`='T' 
 GROUP BY `ID`, PubDate) p

 ON p.I_UnitID = b.I_UnitID AND b.ID=p.ID 
 INNER JOIN matter AS m ON b.ID=m.ID
 WHERE p.ID IS NOT NULL AND m.CreatedBy='12130' AND p.PubDate>CURDATE()
 GROUP BY p.ID ORDER BY p.ID DESC LIMIT 0,6
```

Comment: Could you please show your work..

Comment: if you really want anyone to help please provide the following...sql query, ado.net code, and table schema (including columns data types)

Comment: MySql query updated. please check it.

Comment: From what you posted it looks like what is returned from DB is trimmed to 256 chars. Check your ASP code to make sure return parameter type has more that 256 chars.